# React-Native Modal hangs up

Tags: react-native

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, Image, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ModalBox = props => {
    let ModalContent = null;
    if (props.selectedPlace) {
        ModalContent = (
            <View>
                <Image source={props.selectedPlace.image} style={styles.image} ></Image>
                <Text style= {styles.text}>{props.selectedPlace.value}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Modal onRequestClose={props.close} visible={props.selectedPlace !== null} animationType="slide">
            <View style={styles.ModalContainer}>
                {ModalContent} 
                <Button title="Delete" color="red" onPress={props.itemDelete}></Button>
                <Button title="Close" onPress={props.close}></Button>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ModalContainer: {
        marginTop: 10
    },
    image: {
        height:200,
        width: "100%"
    },
    text:{
        textAlign:"center",
        fontWeight:"bold",
        fontSize: 28
    }
})

export default ModalBox;
```

I have above code for Modal.
When i open my modal and then do some changes in my code and then reloads it. Modal hangs up, not able to even click on my buttons and reload the app too. i have to close my app then start again.

Comment: I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with your code but with React Native [Modal itself](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17986). It has been there across several releases. The best known workaround is using a library like [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) that has its own modal implementation.